# How many bytes are used?

Tags: java, memory, byte

Consider an object of type MysteryBox that stores N items of type boolean
in an array item[] of length N.

```
public class MysteryBox {       // 16B (object overhead)
    private int N;              // 4B (int)
    private boolean[] items;    // 8B (reference to array)
                        // 24B (header of array)
                        // N (boolean array of size N)
// 4B for padding
// 17N (boolean objects, 16B of object metadata, 1B of data equivalent to 1 boolean)
    ...
}
```

how many bytes are used as a function of N (64-bit memory cost model)? Is my answer correct?

Comment: Not a direct answer for your question, but probably a `java.util.BitSet` might be a good idea for storing this kind of information (probably that was designed to be efficient).

Comment: Shouldn't the `int` be 64bit on the stack of a 64bit system? Also the class metadata must be loaded and each instance of the class consumes memory on stack and heap.

Comment: far as I remember, booleans are stored on 4 bytes each

Comment: @Hannes No, int has a defined size on the JVM (it is 32 bit) on every platform. Long is 64 bit.

Comment: @GáborBakos I think the question was about padding, i.e. whether an `int` member is padded to a 64 bit word length.

Comment: The specs says that an int will have the same range on 32 and 64bit systems. But since it's on the stack I'm not quite sure of the actual size it takes.

Comment: Maybe have a play around with http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/ to see what it reports.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out experimentally!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean(); //This might cause a little bit of error
    for(int N=1400;N<5000;N+=100) //this is on the stack, so it shouldn't affect us
    {
        int[] reserved = new int[1000]; //we'll clear this later
        MysteryBox box = new MysteryBox(N);
        int count = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                MysteryBox temp = new MysteryBox(N);
                temp.next = box; //don't worry, this extra variable was subtracted out during analysis
                box=temp;
                count++;
            }
            catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                reserved = null;
                MemoryUsage heapUsage = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
                long maxMemory = heapUsage.getMax();
                long usedMemory = heapUsage.getUsed();
                System.out.println(N+ " : " + count + " : Memory Use :" + usedMemory + "/" + maxMemory + "");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result: Memory use per MysteryBox is extremely linear (r^2 rounds to 1) with respect to N. Memory usage in bytes is given by 1.0052N+33.84. So, apparently each boolean takes up about one byte and all of the rest of the overhead fits into about 34 bytes. I'll leave it to you to speculate about how the overhead is distributed.